# EF 6 and ListView SelectMethod

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, listview

I have a Listview in VS 2013 and I'm trying to use the SelectMethod with EF 6 and VB.  The first part of the listview is this:

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" selectmethod="ListView1_GetData" 
    InsertItemPosition="LastItem" 
    DataKeyNames="SectorId" 
    UpdateMethod="ListView1_UpdateItem" >
```

The ListView1_GetData works perfectly to populate the list - which just has 3 fields.  This is the VB code:

```
Private myentity As New RoutesEntities()
Public Function ListView1_GetData() As IQueryable(Of Sector)
    Return From myuserlist In myentity.Sectors Select myuserlist
End Function
```

The list appears as expected with the "edit" button for this part of the listview:

```
<EditItemTemplate>
   <tr style="background-color:#008A8C;color: #FFFFFF;">
     <td>
       <asp:Button ID="UpdateButton" runat="server" CommandName="Update" 
         Text="Update" CausesValidation="False" />
       <asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" 
         Text="Cancel" CausesValidation="False" />
     </td>
     <td>
       <asp:Label ID="SectorIdLabel1" runat="server" style= "width:40px" Text='<%#Eval "SectorId") %>' />
     </td>
     <td>
       <asp:TextBox ID="SectorTitleTextBox" runat="server" 
         Text='<%# Bind("SectorTitle") %>' />
     </td>
     <td>
       <asp:TextBox ID="SectorDescriptionTextBox" runat="server" 
         Text='<%# Bind("SectorDescription") %>' />
     </td>
         </tr>
 </EditItemTemplate>
```

Here is the beginning of the method to actually do the update:

```
   ' The id parameter name should match the DataKeyNames value set on the control
Public Sub ListView1_UpdateItem(ByVal Sectorid As Integer)
    Dim theID As String
    theID = Sectorid
    MsgBox(theID)
End Sub
```

VS2013 creates the sub and I replaced "id" with my "Sectorid".  As I click on different rows in the list and click the update button, I'm taken to this sub and the correct ID comes up in the MsgBox.  From this point I'm totally stuck as to how to proceed.  I can't find a VB tutorial that relates to what I'm trying to do.  This SelectMethod seems to be a good idea, but there doesn't seem to be much info about how to use it.  Any advice or pointer to a VB tutorial will be much appreciated.

**UPDATE - CODE BELOW WORKS**

With many thanks to Imar I've moving forward now and thought I'd share the update routine for anyone else that might have the same need.  Please note that I'm not a professional programmer and surely others can improve this code - but it works for me and provides the kind of flexibility I want for other pages in my site.  This page was just a easy place to first test this model.

```
 Imports System.Linq
 Imports RoutesEntities
 Partial Class Management_SectorMaint
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
Private myentity As New RoutesEntities()
Public Function ListView1_GetData() As IQueryable(Of Sector)
    Return From myuserlist In myentity.Sectors Select myuserlist
End Function

Protected Sub Page_Unload(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Unload
    If myentity IsNot Nothing Then
        myentity.Dispose()
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub ListView1_UpdateItem(ByVal sectorid As Integer, ByVal sectortitle As String, ByVal sectordescription As String)

    Dim items As Sector = Nothing
    Dim sectoridnumber As Integer
    Dim mysectortitle As String
    Dim mysectordescription As String

    sectoridnumber = sectorid
    mysectortitle = sectortitle
    mysectordescription = sectordescription

    items = (From s In myentity.Sectors
                       Where s.SectorId = sectoridnumber
                       Select s).Single()
    If items Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox("Bad sectorID")
        Return
    End If
    items.SectorTitle = mysectortitle
    items.SectorDescription = mysectordescription

    TryUpdateModel(items)
    If ModelState.IsValid Then
        myentity.SaveChanges()
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class

Here is a partial screen shot of the"admin only" page for the code above:

http://www.bikex.net/sectorMaintPix.png

**IMPROVED CODE**

Per Imar here is a cleaned up version:

```
  Public Sub ListView1_UpdateItem(sector As Sector)

    Dim items As Sector = Nothing
    items = (From s In myentity.Sectors
                       Where s.SectorId = sector.SectorId
                       Select s).Single()
    If items Is Nothing Then
        msglabel.Text = " Failed"      'jquery handles hide-show Div and using a client registered "isPostBack" Var
        Return
    End If
    items.SectorTitle = sector.SectorTitle
    items.SectorDescription = sector.SectorDescription

    TryUpdateModel(items)
    If ModelState.IsValid Then
        myentity.SaveChanges()
        msglabel.Text = " Successful"
    End If
End Sub
```

**FINAL VERSION**

Many thanks to Imar for his coaching - this version works perfectly:

```
 <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" selectmethod="ListView1_GetData"
    ItemType="Sector" 
    DataKeyNames="SectorId" 
    UpdateMethod="ListView1_UpdateItem"> 
<AlternatingItemTemplate>
   <tr style="background-color:#FFF8DC;">
     <td>.............

 Imports System.Linq
 Imports RoutesEntities
 Partial Class Management_SectorMaint
 Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
 Private myContext As New RoutesEntities()
 Public Function ListView1_GetData() As IQueryable(Of Sector)
    Return From myuserlist In myContext.Sectors Select myuserlist
 End Function

Public Sub ListView1_UpdateItem(sector As Sector)
    Dim item As Sector = (From s In myContext.Sectors
                     Where s.SectorId = sector.SectorId
                     Select s).SingleOrDefault()
    If item Is Nothing Then
        msglabel.Text = " Failed"
        Return
    End If
    TryUpdateModel(item)
    item.SectorTitle = String.Concat(sector.SectorTitle, " test") ' A change to "item" here goes to DB
    If ModelState.IsValid Then
        myContext.SaveChanges()
        msglabel.Text = " Successful"
    Else
        msglabel.Text = " Fail"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: While this works, it's typically easier to create a single parameter in UpdateItem of your entity type. E.g.:

`Public Sub ListView1_UpdateItem(sector As Sector)`

assuming that Sector is your item type, and you set ItemType on the list control to Sector.

Comment: BTW: You shouldn't use MsgBox. While it appears to work, it's actually a server side message box and won't work if the client is not the same machine as the server. Use JavaScript's alert or other means instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the ItemType property of the ListView to the type of your entity. This makes the control strongly typed. Then you can change the Sectorid property in the UpdateItem method from an int to your type (a Sector, a User, what have you). ASP.NET will then populate your instance with data coming from the form.

As an alternative, you van also call TryUpdateModel and pass in a fresh instance of your model class which then gets populated,.

More details can be found in this [Model Binding tutorial](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/03/28/tutorial-series-on-model-binding-with-asp-net-web-forms.aspx).

Comment: Thank you very much! This tutorial is exactly what I was looking for.  As much as I looked around, I never found this.  I'll work through the tutorial before I go back to my website.